# Adding Elements,Nodes and Text in XMl in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

I want to add an elements ,nodes to an existing Xml.
I am using the below mentioned Code ,but not getting proper output of Xml.

```
 XmlNode root=doc.SelectSingleNode("DB");
 XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("ScopeCleanUp");
 root.AppendChild(elem);
 XmlNode rootLoc= doc.SelectSingleNode("DBSync/ScopeCleanUp");
 XmlElement elemLoc = doc.CreateElement("LocalScope");           
 XmlNode rootScope = doc.SelectSingleNode("DBSync/ScopeCleanUp/LocalScope");
 for (int s = 0; s < 2; s++)
 {
     XmlElement elemScope = doc.CreateElement("ScopeName");
     elemScope.InnerText = s.ToString();
     rootLoc.AppendChild(elemScope);                       
 }
 rootLoc.AppendChild(elemLoc);
```

I need the Xml as below Output.

```
<DB>
<ScopeCleanUp>
<LocalDataBase>
<ScopeName>1</ScopeName> 
<ScopeName>2</ScopeName> 
  </LocalDataBase>
</ScopeCleanUp>
</DB>
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "proper output of Xml"? And what are you currently getting (there is no output in your code, so can't understand what you are currently trying)?

Comment: I meant proper Output is the Xml which I have provided is to be achieved.I adding further the Xml which I am getting `<DB><ScopeCleanUp> <ScopeName>0</ScopeName> <ScopeName>1</ScopeName> <LocalScope /> </ScopeCleanUp></DB>`
If you see the difference, is the presence of Element'LocalDatabase.

Comment: Please let me know if any thing is unclear.

Comment: This does not help a lot. Please edit your question so that it is clear what the source xml, the target xml you currently generate and the target xml you want to generate is.

Comment: Target Xml to be achieved 
`<DB> <ScopeCleanUp> <LocalDataBase> <ScopeName>1</ScopeName> <ScopeName>2</ScopeName> </LocalDataBase> </ScopeCleanUp> </DB>' Xml generated by above Code mentioned
`<DB> <ScopeCleanUp> <ScopeName>0</ScopeName> <ScopeName>1</ScopeName> <LocalScope /> </ScopeCleanUp> </DB>`
The difference is the presence of the node LocalScope.The tag should open after ScopeCleanUp and close before ScopeCleanUp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
        XmlElement db = doc.CreateElement("DB");
        XmlElement scope = doc.CreateElement("ScopeCleanUp");
        XmlElement local = doc.CreateElement("LocalDataBase");

        doc.AppendChild(db);
        db.AppendChild(scope);
        scope.AppendChild(local);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("ScopeName");
            elem.InnerText = i.ToString();
            local.AppendChild(elem);
        }
```